# Can a connection be established from copper wire to stainless steel bus for power connection?

Tags: wire, steel, copper, stainless

I have this question.

A copper cable to be connected(either crimped/ soldered/ pressure/screw fitted) to stainless steel bus bar and the bus bar is to be connected to the power supply of 12 V DC.

Now I have the following queries:

1. Can a connection be possible from copper wire to Stainless steel bus bar ? If yes, what are the factors need to be considered ? Can copper wire be connected to copper coated stainless steel bus bar ?
2. What type of connection between copper wire and steel is feasible( crimping,clamping , screw etc).
3. In my case, coating of stainless steel with any metal will make the connection feasible? if possible also the electric transfer efficiency of the connection in various cases?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this looks to be more of an EE problem than a mains electricity one...

Answer (score 1):

I think you are way over thinking this. Take your copper cable and crimp an appropriately sized copper ring terminal onto the end. Then drill and tap a threaded hole in the stainless steel bus bar that takes a screw of a size to fit nicely in the hole of the ring terminal. Simply screw the terminal to the bus bar and be done with the job.

Obviously it is up to you to select the proper sized copper cable, crimp terminal and screw that are rated for the amount of current that you want to transfer into or out of the bus bar.

Comment: Thankyou Karas ,

I am more interested in technical feasibility of connection between copper wire and stainless steel bus bar, 
Will the electric properties (current carrying capacity of the connection ) vary because of the connection.
Does plating of Stainless steel with any metal reduce the dielectric corrosion at the junction.
Any relevant information is more than welcome ..thanks in advance